# In Python what could cause a for loop to randomly go backwards in value?

Tags: python, loops, sqlite

What can cause an iterator to go forwards in a loop, and then backwards?

This is the code I'm using to loop through the table's primary key field. The primary key is being used to populate initial values in a separate table.

For loop:

```
for row in sampleDB.select_fromTable():
    print row[0]
    sampleDB.insert_toTable(row[0], 2.0)
```

sqllite insert statement:

```
def insert_toTable(self, primaryKey, initial):
    c = self.conn.cursor()
    c.execute('insert into insert_toTable VALUES(?, ?)', (primaryKey, initial))
    if c.rowcount == 1:
        print "Updated row.\n"
    else:
        print "Row does not exist.\n"

    self.conn.commit()
    c.close()
```

The select statement that creates the tuple to loop through:

```
def select_fromTable(self):
    c = self.conn.cursor()
    c.execute('select * from sampleTable')

    c.close

    return c
```

Here is an example table:

```
Primary Key     Text
0               John
1               Sue
2               Bill
3               Tyler
```

Running the loop without the insert statement prints each unique key once, but if I add the call to the insert function (insert_toTable) I get this phenomenon:

```
0
Updated row.

1
Updated row.

0
Traceback (most recent call last):
sqlite3.IntegrityError: column urlid is not unique
```

The next iteration of the loop should be to the unique value "2" not back to "0"....

I can provide more sections of code if needed.

Comment: After posting this, I tried commenting out the commit statement and that fixed this weird thing, but why?

Comment: Should you be using an [SQL `UPDATE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_(SQL)) statement instead of `INSERT`?

Comment: As far as I know, `commit` is only for transactions.

Comment: I'm curious, why does this post have the `eclipse` tag?

Comment: @sarnold, SQL UPDATE didn't apply because this table is empty, and therefore no rows to update.


@Elxx, you were right, commit is only for UPDATEs and other transactions.


@dappawit, I tagged it with eclipse because that is the IDE I am using in conjunction with pydev. I was sure of what was causing the odd behavior and so tagged eclipse and pydev in case they could have been culprits.

Comment: @SprocketGizmo: Fair enough.  If you think it may be a cause of the issue, then next time you may want to mention it in your post :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the results of this code may change depending on exactly which versions of sqlite and python are used.

Notice that your call to `c.close` in the `select_fromTable` method should be `c.close()`. This is a fortunate error, since you cannot iterate over the results of the query after the cursor is closed. However, the result is that you have two open cursors in the loop.

Try changing your `select_fromTable` method to:

```
def select_fromTable(self):
    c = self.conn.cursor()
    c.execute('select * from sampleTable')
    results = c.fetchall()
    c.close()
    return results
```

and see what happens. I believe it will fix your problem.